# Angular 7: How to increase the time of an angular request

Tags: javascript, angular, request, timeout

I need to increase the request time of the angular app because using slow internet connections timeout happens.

I tried the code below and had an error.

```
this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers })
            .timeout(100, this.handleTimeout)
            .map(response =>{
                return response;
            })
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
```

> Property 'timeout' does not exist on type
>   'Observable'.ts(2339)

Not success using interceptor too

```
@Injectable()
export class AngularInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).timeout(5000);
}
```

> Property 'timeout' does not exist on type
>   'Observable>'.ts(2339)

Thanks

Comment: What is the version of Rxjs that you are using?

Comment: Hey, it is "rxjs": "~6.3.3",

Comment: Did you `import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';` ?

Comment: @nicholascm no, it was missing, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solutions that works for me:

```
import { timeout} from 'rxjs/operators';

return this.http.get(`${url}`).pipe(
            timeout(1000)
        );
```

Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

With Rxjs 6, you will have to use a `.pipe` and then use an operator like `.timeout`
So your implementation should look like:

```
import { 
  timeout,
  map,
  catch
} from 'rxjs/operators';


this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers })
            .pipe(
             timeout(100, this.handleTimeout),
             map(response =>{
                return response;
             }),
            catch(this.handleErrors);
```

Comment: Yes, the import was missing, but I had to change the function a little to be able to perform the request. Thanks.